# ASP GridView not showing as Table in Browser source page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a GridView inside an update panel that holds stock code information and is binded to a DataSource based on user search of stock code.

Results are returning fine when user searches for stock code, there are also 2 text boxes and a label field that are added to each row in the gridview that will take user inputs for Order Quantity and Line Discount and finally show Line total respectively.

I am now trying to use onkeyup events and JQuery for these Text boxes to calculate line totals, but nothing works. I have done some checking and see that the Grid View is not populating in HTML table format in the Source code of the web page which leads me to believe that the JQuery is unable to find the control Id's which means it will not be able to do the calculation when onkeyup event is fired. Is there anything I need to be looking for:

ASP:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAddOrderItems" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <asp:GridView ID="grvStockCodes"
                                            runat="server"
                                            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                            CssClass="table table-striped"
                                            AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#E4EAEE">
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E4EAEE" />
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StockCode">
                                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" />
                                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" />
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <div style="float: left">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblStockCode"
                                                                Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StockCode") %>'
                                                                runat="server">
                                                            </asp:Label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="col-md-5 col-sm-5" />
                                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-5 col-sm-5" />
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <div style="float: left">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblDescription"
                                                                Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description") %>'
                                                                runat="server">
                                                            </asp:Label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price(excl)">
                                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" />
                                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" />
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <div style="float: left">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblPrice"
                                                                Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SellingPrice") %>'
                                                                ItemStyle-CssClass="price"
                                                                runat="server">
                                                            </asp:Label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OrderQty">
                                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" />
                                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" />
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <div style="float: left">
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrderQty" onKeyUp="CalculateTotals();"
                                                                runat="server">
                                                            </asp:TextBox>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Discount">
                                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" />
                                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" />
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <div style="float: left">
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDiscount"
                                                                runat="server">
                                                            </asp:TextBox>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LineTotal(excl))">
                                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" />
                                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" />
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <div style="float: left">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblLineTotal"
                                                                runat="server"
                                                                Text ="0.00">
                                                            </asp:Label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                            </Columns>
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="divider gap-top-20 gap-bottom-45"></div>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnConfirmOrderDetails" runat="server" Text="Confirm Order Details" CssClass="btn btn-primary pull-right" OnClick="btnConfirmOrderDetails_Click" />
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

JQuery

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function CalculateTotals() {
            $("[id*=txtOrderQty]").val("0");
        });
        $("[id*=txtOrderQty]").live("change", function () {
            if (isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
                $(this).val('0');
            } else {
                $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()).toString());
            }
        });
        $("[id*=txtOrderQty]").live("keyup", function () {
            if (!jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
                    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                    $("[id*=lblLineTotal]", row).html(parseFloat($(".price", row).html()) * parseFloat($(this).val()));
                }
            } else {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: John, You have done a fine enough job of describing your issue. You should consider adding some of your relevant (jquery) code.

Comment: My apologies. Code added.@DaniDev

Comment: I must also admit that I am not a Jquery developer by any means and this is a best attempt scenario so far from code snippets off other forums.

Comment: @John_86 What version of jQuery are you using? `.live` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: @Santi - <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Again, this is best attempt scenario so I have no clue what versions needs to be used, this is code from another forum that I am trying to get working. I would be open to a complete rewrite of the Jquery code to try and get it working.

Comment: " unable to find the control Id's " Which controls are you not able to locate?
Try putting alerts to see which controls are being located and which are not.

Comment: which are the controls you are trying to calculate?
lblLineTotal  or  txtOrderQty or txtDiscount or Price

Comment: @DaniDev I am attempting to calculate lblLineTotal based on inputs for txtOrderQty and txtDiscount. ie - lblLineTotal = ((lblPrice * txtOrderQty)  - txtDiscount).

Comment: Do you know how far are you getting in your jquery code?

Comment: @DaniDev - Not a clue. As I said, my jquery knowledge is laughable at best. I'd rather be honest and ask for help than pretend I know what I am doing.

Comment: Yeah, I gottcha. What you need is a little JavaScript expertise. You have to try to do it little at a time rather than just finding some code pasting it in an hoping it works.
First thing, try to make sure your code is getting triggered. then try to locate and read the values. then try to do the calculation.

Comment: look up how to 'alert()' so you know what is happening.

Comment: Thanx @DaniDev. Going to be a slow process but will give it a go.